# Stack divs when one overflows

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've been trying to find a CSS only solution to this but can't think of one so I figured I would ask.

Given three divs all horizontally stacked next to one another, when one div overflows to the next line how can you change the layout so that they switch to being vertically stacked.

I've added a code snippet with a button of which when you click it, it will set the width of the parent div element. This is meant to be an example of the window resizing so that the parent element ends up too small to allow all the divs on the same line at which time the divs should maneuver into a vertical stack.

For now I'm using javascript to determine if the height of the div ever increases in size on element resize but if there is a CSS only solution that would be ideal.

```js
function forceOverflow() {
  let container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
  if (container.className.indexOf('small') !== -1) {
    container.className = "container";
  } else  {
    container.className = "container small";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: yellow;
}

.container.small {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Dynamic string 1</div>
  <div>Dynamic string 2</div>
  <div>Dynamic string 3</div>
</div>
<button onClick="forceOverflow()">Force overflow</button>
```

Comment: You're setting the width to an arbitrary size, which in this case just so happens to not wrap into a column at 300px (based on the content inside of each div). However, had you set the size to 200px it would work accordingly (based on said content). This is a good use case for media queries, is that not an option for you? You said your already checking if the height changes, why not just add a media query for *if screen width is less than xxx* or *if screen width is more than xxx* `flex-flow: column`. Media queries are inherently conditional, and pure CSS.

Comment: you can't *detect* wrapping in CSS, you should use `media queries`...

Comment: The reason media queries don't apply here is because it's a component used in several locations all with varying widths. Media queries are extremely specific to particular use cases but not great in regards to reusable components where the parent consuming the computer can place it at any arbitrary width.

Comment: maybe you could use grids instead of flex: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this kind of conditional logic with CSS, because you would need to query the DOM to do so and that's not something CSS is capable of.